# How can I set a Facebook iframe like button to add current page URL to href on meteor app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor

Hy

I want to add facebook iframe like button to my meteor app, but with a dynamic one not static; means, I ll share any page I want not only one page ( one url)
thank's à lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query string you are expected to pass to the src of the iframe like this :

```
<template name="facebookButton">
  <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="facebook-button"
    src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?{{queryString}}">
  </iframe>
</template>
```

We use a simple helper to build the query string, it will be reactive and we can feed it with the current url (location.href).

```
Template.facebookButton.helpers({
  queryString:function(){
    var parameters={
      href:encodeURIComponent(location.href),
      send:"false",
      layout:"box_count",
      show_faces:"false",
      action:"like",
      font:"arial",
      colorscheme:"light"
    };
    var pairs=_.pairs(parameters);
    var pairsJoined=_.map(pairs,function(pair){
      return pair.join("=");
    });
    return pairsJoined.join("&");
  }
});
```

EDIT : forgot to URI encode the href param.

Comment: is it possible to do something like that  <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fklfilm.meteor.com%2Flinks%2F5CiAx6kn8yx8s5YSS&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe> but dynamic ?

Comment: This is basically the whole idea of the code sample I gave you if you replace with the good values.

Comment: Thank's a lot man, it works well; juste one more thing, how to rendere   text with every post because now it rendere a title text with every post???

Comment: When i share post on Facebook, i want to be shared with its title, how can i do it ?

Comment: To be more clear, there is a lot of film post, so i want to share the link of film i like with the title of film not title of document

Comment: something like this [link](http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-create-a-custom-facebook-share-button-for-your-iframe-tab/)

Comment: Apparently using an iframe to share a link is deprecated, you should use the method described here instead (using HTML5 + facebook JavaScript SDK) : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/, if you have problems implementing this you should ask another question.

Comment: That what i did the first time but no button rendered when i used html